# Itererating over class properties in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, oop, object, class-properties

I created a class based on a list of variables that comes from data. I made a function that will place all data inside an object of this class.

As the list of variables grows, I keep having to adjust the class and the load function. I am trying to find a way that will make my load function robust against changes in the class.

Code of the Class file:

```
classdef CoolClass
    properties
        prop_a
        prop_b
        prop_c
    end
end
```

The function I wrote to load this data into an object:

```
function [ object_name ] = loadCoolClass (data_file_name)

    load(data_file_name) 
    % this loads the variabels: 
    % prop_a = 1, prop_b = 2, prop_c = 3, prop_d = 4

    object_name = CoolClass;

    object_name.prop_a = prop_a;
    object_name.prop_b = prop_b;
    object_name.prop_c = prop_c;
end
```

Now what I would like to have is something that if I add a variable `prop_d` to the classdef file that it will immediately load it into the loadfile as well. something like this:

```
function [ object_name ] = loadCoolClass (data_file_name)

    load(data_file_name) 
    % this loads the variabels: 
    % prop_a = 1, prop_b = 2, prop_c = 3, prop_d = 4

    object_name = CoolClass
    cool_properties = properties(CoolClass)

    for i = 1:size(cool_properties,2)
        object_name.cool_property(i) = cool_property(i)
    end
end
```

Now I know the loop above is not valid code but I mean: check for every property if there is a variable with that name and place it in the object.

Is there a way in matlab to use a variable holding a string, as an input to load the value of the variable named after the content of the string?

Is this possible in naming content before the '=' sign
Is this possible in referring to variables after the '=' sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the *easiest* way to do this is to make your class a subclass of [`hgsetget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsetget.html). This gives you the ability to use `set(obj, 'Key', value)` and `get(obj, 'Key', value)` just like you would for graphics objects.

```
cls = CoolClass();
set(cls, 'prop_a', 1)
```

The second step is to [specify an output to `load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#outputarg_S) (rather than just dumping the data into your workspace) which will give you a struct with a field for each variable in the file. This is recommended *whenver* loading from a file to keep your workspace tidy.

Now, the *real* benefit of subclassing `hgsetget` is that [you can *also* pass a `struct` of property/values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-a-set-get-interface-for-properties.html) to `set` and `get`!

### Example

```
classdef CoolClass < hgsetget
    properties
        prop_a
        prop_b
    end
end
```

Now if you have a file `data.mat` that contains values for `prop_a` and `prop_b` you can then do this.

```
cls = CoolClass();
data = load('data.mat')

    prop_a: 1
    prop_b: 2

set(cls, data)
```

If you have variables in `data.mat` that *are not* properties of your class you can easily filter these out and still use `set`.

```
toremove = setdiff(fieldnames(data), props);
set(cls, rmfield(data, toremove);
```

## A Better Example

What I personally would do would be to write a constructor that accepts the same inputs as `set` (i.e. a struct or param/value pairs) and then inside of the constructor, pass them directly to `set`. Also, you can implement a  [`loadobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadobj.html) method for the class which is essentially a static method that accepts a struct as input. You can do all of your validation within that method to remove unwanted fields.

```
classdef CoolClass < hgsetget
    properties
        prop_a
        prop_b
    end

    methods
        function self = CoolClass(varargin)
            set(self, varargin{:});
        end
    end

    methods (Static)
        function obj = loadobj(S)
            obj = CoolClass();

            % Remove any invalid fields
            toremove = setdiff(fieldnames(S), properties(cls));
            set(obj, rmfield(S, toremmove))
        end
    end
end
```

Now you could use this class two other ways than we could previously.

```
cls = CoolClass(load('data.mat'));
cls = CoolClass.loadobj(load('data.mat'));
```

Comment: Wow this is super usefull. I was working on a project with about 30 variables where we are constantly adding and removing them. your solution really helps us reduce the overhead when changing our variables.

Comment: @PacoHamers Glad to help. I have updated with a more complete example which demonstrates how you could modify the constructor to accept these structs as inputs.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if what you are trying to do makes sense but I think you are looking for the function eval:
object_name.cool_property(i) = eval(cool_property(i))

Comment: oh this is indeed what I look for as part of the solution. but it indeed only solves the problem from stuff after the '='.

it still gives an error on 
object_name.cool_property(i) = ...

Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.

Comment: your hint gave me the vital solution for the problem: the solution is: object_name.(char(cool_property(i))) = eval(cool_property(i))

Comment: Noooo please don't use eval and please don't suggest using eval.

Comment: Hey  @rayryeng ! you don't need to downvote my answer please. I agree eval is ugly. But this is what Paco was looking for and I think the closest answer to his question. As I've written I am not sure it makes sense at all. Maybe you have a better answer?

Comment: @ThierryDalon Suever already has a better answer. And if there's a solution without eval, then eval should not be used. And if a user asks and you would want to answer with eval, then don't. Then if you *really* want to answer with eval, do, but *make it clear that eval is both dangerous and as inefficient as can be*. Just dropping it as a "get out of jail free card" is unhelpful, and prepare for criticism from other users. For what it's worth, I didn't downvote your answer.